# Angular 9: Disable label checkbox (not the box)

Tags: css, angular, checkbox

I need it in order to make clickable just a piece of the checkbox label (Privacy Policy). This is the snippet:

```
    <div>
      <mat-checkbox required formControlName="privacyCheck" [checked]="false">
        <b style="color: crimson">*</b>Accetto la
        <i style="color: #770E0E" (click)="printDebug()">privacy policy</i>
        e i termini di condizione dell'utilizzo del servizio.
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
```

At the moment, if i click on the italic text ("privacy policy"), i got the printDebug but of course the checkbox will be setted to "checked".

I tried several solutions using CSS property `pointer-events: none !important;` on `.mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label span`, `.mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-label`, and so on.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a good old fashioned `stopPropagation()`?

<sub>I was a bit too quick with my answer</sub>

You need to do `preventDefault()`, because the content of the `mat-checkbox` will be put inside a `<label>` and it's default browser behavior to check a checkbox if you click on the attached label.

```
<i style="color: #770E0E" (click)="printDebug($event)">privacy policy</i>
```

```
printDebug(event: MouseEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

If you are using the ripple effect from material, this will still be triggered. If you do not want this, you will have to do a `.stopPropagation()` on mousedown:

```
<i style="color: #770E0E" (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
                          (click)="printDebug($event)">privacy policy</i>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwt7sn?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html)

Comment: @Mattia_B I've updated my answer, with a working stackblitz example